# Any Way to Dump Event Log in Crusader Kings 2?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I've found out how to open the console, but when I input debug_dumpevents, it tells me, in red text, that the command is only for developers.

So how can I access the list of events, such as you see scrolling along in the events window in the bottom of the page? I would like to keep record of the historical progression, and I would assume this data is being saved somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to use this command, you have to launch the game with the following parameters :

`-debug -debugscripts`

In Steam, you can right-click on the game, select "Set launch options" and enter that here.

Comment: Since they all use the Clausewitz engine, I imagine that this answer applies to HoI3(and probably 4 when it comes out), EU 3 and 4, and Victoria II as well. I'm sure I'm missing some one-off games as well with the engine.

Comment: @Tarkenfire Most likely.

Comment: Just tested it in EU4, so yeah.

Comment: It is great. I see the dump of events